# Javascript caching property values into the variables

Tags: javascript, json, performance, caching

I've a simple read-only JSON object with a few propeties, I wonder if it's worth caching its properties into the variables? Currently we use them like: `jsonObject.somePropet`y ,I'm considering caching them into the variables like: `var somePropertyValue = jsonObject.somePropety;` and using that var for all future refs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on where jsonObject is stored, and how many scope steps (function closures) away from where it's being used it is.

e.g. in the example below each time jsonObject.prop is accessed the code checks the scoped variables of 6 different scopes (including the global scope) before it finds jsonObject

```
var jsonObject = { ... };

(function() {
    (function() {
        (function() {
            (function() {
               (function() {
                    jsonObject.prop ...;
                    jsonObject.prop ...;
                })();
             })();
         })();
    })();
})();
```

So if the property is being accessed multiple times in the innermost function it makes sense to save a local reference to it

```
var jsonObject = { ... };

(function() {
    (function() {
        (function() {
            (function() {
               (function() {
                    var prop = jsonObject.prop;
                })();
             })();
         })();
    })();
})();
```

Now (apart from the first time the property is accessed to write it to the variable) your code has to do a lot less work to find the value.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you judge "worth" on this issue.

Caching the properties should have some theoretical performance gain if using the same property repeatedly, but I doubt that the difference will be noticeable to the user unless you're looping many thousands of times.

Caching the properties can make your code prettier though, e.g., if you are referring to the same property more than a couple of times in a particular block of code you could cache it at the beginning - especially if you've got nested objects like this:

```
jsonObject.nestedObject.doSomething();
jsonObject.nestedObject.doAnotherThing();
alert(jsonObject.nestedObject.someProperty);

//compared with:
var nObj = jsonObject.nestedObject;
nObj.doSomething();
nObj.doAnotherThing();
alert(nObj);
```

I find the latter easier to type and easier to read (at least, it would be easier to read if the variable `nObj` had a more meaningful name, but obviously this is just a generic example).

I would not, however, cache the properties in *global* variables for use throughout all of your code. Keeping globals to a minimum is almost always a good idea for several reasons, including avoiding clashes in naming with included libraries, and avoiding hard-to-diagnose bugs where multiple functions update the same variable. Just cache within individual functions that happen to need to use a particular property a lot - and remember that JS has *function* scope not *block* scope. (Where a particular function references a particular property a lot you could also consider making that property an argument to the function for the same effect with (arguably) neater code.)

P.S. JavaScript doesn't have JSON objects, it just has objects.